# Integrating AdminLTE into Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, integration

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and wanted to install a free template called AdminLTE.
It allows you to easily create App (front-end).

I wanted to integrate it into Rails but I didn't know how and I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

If anyone can help me that would be awesome.

this is the template's website: https://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got this implemented just last night. Here's how I did it.

Paste this into your `Gemfile :`

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'

source 'https://rails-assets.org/' do 
  gem 'rails-assets-adminlte'
end
```

Paste the following to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require adminlte
```

Paste the following to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
*= require adminlte
*= require skin-blue
```

Create a new file `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss` and paste in the following:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

From the source code of AdminLTE that is downloaded separately which you may get from the link you mentioned in your question, browse to

```
dist/css/skin
```

and copy the file `skin-blue.css` and paste it into `vendor/assets/stylesheets/` in your rails project

Then open the `starter.html` in the source code of AdminLTE and paste the content within the `<body>  .........  </body>` and paste it within the `<body>  ................ </body>` in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` . Modify the body tag to to `<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">`

Install the included gems by running `bundle install` and then restart rails server by running `rails s` and you should see the the beautiful template that is AdminLTE

NOTE 1: Maybe there exist other, more efficient ways of doing it. I am not aware though and if anyone knows, I'd be more than glad to learn how it's done. Until then, this works perfectly for me and I hope it saves you some precious time.

NOTE 2: You may of course change the skin to your liking accordingly by changing the stylesheet file you include in the `vendor/assets/stylesheets` and making the necessary modifications to your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file. Don't forget to change the class of the `<body > .......</body>` in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file

Comment: it works fine on local system but giver error while deploying
"Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'adminlte' with type 'application/javascript'"

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal add this line `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to your application.js

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to copy 'skin-blue.css' into

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/
```

Paste the following to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
//= require adminlte/skins/skin-blue
```