# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'adminlte' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adminlte

I followed [stack overfolw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150408/integrating-adminlte-into-ruby-on-rails)

to add adminlte in my rails app

it also says to add

```
//= require adminlte
```

in application.js

it works fine on local system but now  when I am trying to deploy to digital ocean droplet it gives error

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'adminlte' with type 'application/javascript'
```

My gemfile(I removed all gems except relavent) to clear the adminlte issue

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'bundler', '>= 1.8.4'

gem 'pnotify-rails'

  source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
    gem 'rails-assets-adminlte', '2.3.3'
  end

end
```

I normal cases we write

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'pnotify-rail'
```

and in application.js

```
//= require pnotify
```

and don't include any file like pnotify.js manully

But in this case I instead used

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
    gem 'rails-assets-adminlte', '2.3.3'
  end
```

and for this 
`//= require adminlte` causing issue

Comment: Did you pre compile your assets on production ? Remember when you deploy ur app on production you also need to precompile assets. In Capistrano, go the capfile and uncomment the assets line and then redeploy

Comment: I didn't pre compile them
let me to try this

Comment: In capfile I don't have assets line
which line are you pointing out?

Comment: I'm on phone now. Won't be able to show where to find it. You could google precompile assets with Capistrano 3 

Comment: @PamioSolanky
I precompiled them, there is no issue in precompilation.
but when try to deploy it says "Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'adminlte' with type 'application/javascript'"

Answer (score 0):

From What I understand, you do not have a file named `adminlte` in your javascript folder.

Your `app/assets/javascripts/` must have all the files that you want to require in your `application.js`

So if you have required `adminlte`, you must also have a file with the same name in your javascripts folder.

I see that you are using a theme, you might want to consider copying all the javascript and css files to the respective folders. If you have a folder to require, you could use `// require_tree ./adminlte` which requires all the files in that folder.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually I 'm using    source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
    gem 'rails-assets-adminlte', '2.3.3'
  end
for simple gem , we simple write //require pnotify etc.
but something I 'm missing in "https://rails-assets.org" case

Comment: Sorry didn't quite get that ?? actually you are using.. what ?

Comment: just a minute
let me edit the question with gem file to clarify this

Comment: I added my gem file with and some description to clarify this, kindly have a look

Comment: Not sure about this but it looks like its manly for bower components. However, you said it works fine on your local machine in your previous question so I assume that its available on rails-assets. Did you bundle install while deploying the site on production ?

Comment: You might have to share more info on this as its not clear as to why this would happen. You might as well consider looking at the page source on your local and see where is the `adminlte` coming from. I mean whats the path of the file. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, having to import `adminlte` on some servers and `AdminLTE` on others.

Just use `rails-assets-admin-lte` instead of `rails-assets-adminlte` (they're based on the same code) and import `admin-lte` instead of `adminlte` in your CSS and JS application files.